# MongoDB replica set prioriy

Tags: mongodb

I've set up a very simple MongDB project on three servers. Since it's a test deployment, I have configured the three config servers on the three sharding servers. Each replica set consists of three nodes which are in different servers.

I think  all my nodes in the replica set are primary, since I haven't defined any priority yet.

How can I modify two of them to be secondary?
The other question I have is that, shouldn't I have one primary and one secondary in one server and another one in another server?

Comment: This is more of a configuration question than a software development question, so I nominated this question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: As well I think you are confusing sharded sets with replica sets for one.

Comment: Thank you guy. I'm sort of a newbie here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has no multi-master replication. It simply does not allow to have more than one primary in a replica-set. So you very certainly have one primary and two secondaries. The primary is selected by the servers themselves [through an election](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) which [you can manipulate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetConfig/#replSetGetConfig.members[n].priority) when you want a specific server to be primary.

To find out if a server is a primary or a secondary, connect to the node with the `mongo` shell, and enter `db.isMaster()`. More information about all members of the replica-set can be obtained with `rs.status()`. It shows you the hostnames and roles of all replica-set members.

Comment: Thank you very much Philip. but why is my data exactly the same size on each server(node)? Aren't they just copies of each other?

Comment: @MohammadAmin That's what replication does: Every node of the replica-set mirrors the same data. Differences can occur when the secondaries are behind the primary.

Comment: @Philibp Oh, You're right. I was confusing it with Arbiter. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I know I seriously need to read the docs again, but I have a question. If I want to split the data in Mongo, can I use one collection for two or more shards? How?  Because I read it in the docs that shards are per collection. If I scale out horizontally, I'm just copying the same data over and over again. How can I split the data?

Comment: @MohammadAmin I think you are a bit confused about the difference between [replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) and [sharded clusters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/).